# Replace only whole words c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a function replacing only whole words, for example:

The sentence : "#testing is #test", if I use Replace("#test", "#cool"), I'll have "#cooling if #cool" but I'd like to have "#testing is #cool"

I've searched and every answer found was :

```
string pattern = @"\b"+previousText+"\b";
string myText = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, newText, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

However this solution does not work if my previousText (the one I'd like to replace) contains a "#".

Both my previousText and my newText can start with a "#".

What is the solution for this ?

EDIT : Thanks to Legends the regex now works if the word is followed by a space but fails if the searched word is next to a comma :

```
string input = "#test, #test";
            string patternTest = @"#test";
            string newTextTest = "#cool";
            string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?:(?<=^|\s)(?=\S|$)|(?<=^|\S)(?=\s|$))" + patternTest + @"(?:(?<=^|\s)(?=\S|$)|(?<=^|\S)(?=\s|$))", newTextTest, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

this returns : "#test, #cool" instead of "#cool, #cool"

Comment: You must use Regex for that

Comment: seems to work with word boundary only after the hash tag `@"#test\b"` or `@"#\btest\b"`

Answer (score 2):

The following Regex will replace only **single whole words**!

```
var input = "#testing is #test";
var pattern = @"#test";
string myText = 
Regex.Replace(input, @"(?:(?<=^|\s)(?=\S|$)|(?<=^|\S)(?=\s|$))" + pattern + @"(?:(?<=^|\s)(?=\S|$)|(?<=^|\S)(?=\s|$))","#cool", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

**Result:**

> #testing is #cool

---

**This should work with commas and semicolons directly before and after the word**:

```
var input = "#test, is ;#test";
var searchString = @"#test";
var replaceWith = "#cool";
var pattern = @"(?:(?<=^|(\s|,|;))(?=\S|$)|(?<=^|\S)(?=\s|$))" 
              + searchString + 
              @"(?:(?<=^|(\s))(?=\S|$)|(?<=^|\S)(?=(\s|,|;)|$))";

string myText = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replaceWith, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

**Result:**

> #cool, is ;#cool

---

**This one will work with all the following characters before and after the word**

For example:

1. ,word or word,
2. word; or ;word
3. .word or ....

> , ; . - '

```
var input = "#test's is #test.";
var searchString = @"#test";
var replaceWith = "#cool";
var pattern = @"(?:(?<=^|(\s|,|;|-|:|\.|'))(?=\S|$)|(?<=^|\S)(?=\s|$))" 
              + searchString + 
              @"(?:(?<=^|(\s))(?=\S|$)|(?<=^|\S)(?=(\s|,|;|-|:|\.|')|$))";
string myText = Regex.Replace(input,pattern ,replaceWith, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

**Result:**

> #cool's is #cool.

Comment: Fails on "apostrophe es". Fails on hyphenation.

Comment: It seems to fail if the word is followed by a comma, see my edit for the example.

Comment: you can get more and more specific, this and that and .... ;-) Updated my answer.

Comment: @Aron The OP asked "Replace only whole words" and this is what it perfectly does. A word does not consist of special characters like `",!;:"`.
This solution is far from all in one solution, but this wasn't asked for.

Comment: @Legend but it does not tokenise correctly for certain edge cases.... Like punctuation.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work if my word finishes by a number, ex: #test12, if I use your regex to replace #test by #cool I'll have #cool12

Comment: I tested this: `"#test's is #test12"` ->execute-> `#cool's is #test12` .
And this works... perhaps I didn't get you..?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use regex for some reason, you can do it without it as well:

```
var split_options = new [] {' ', '.', ',' ...}; // Use whatever you might have here.
var input =  "#testing is #test".Split( split_options
                                      , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var word_to_replace = "#test";
var new_text = "#cool";
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    if (input[i].Equals(word_to_replace))
    input[i] = new_text;
}
var output = string.Join(" ",input);

// your output is "#testing is #cool"
```

You can put this in a method or extension method, and it'll make you're code cleaner as well.

Comment: I didn't try this solution before, i thought it would be more ugly to do, nice example. I'll compare the performance vs the Regex

Comment: Same same, but different, just giving you options :). to be honest, i believe regex should be slower, but for all practical uses, it wouldn't matter. I'll edit it to address comments on other answer as wel.

Comment: _NOTE_:  This code has the side effect of replacing any non-space "split option" characters (period and comma in the example given) with spaces.  So if you wanted to replace only whole word instances of, "Test" in the text, "Test,Testing,Testeroo" you would end up with, "Newvalue Testing Testeroo".